Gradle process sync failed
gradle is failing to sync i tried invalidate and restarting, sdk manager, and making sure that gradle is in the correct location but still get this error please help
i tried different kinds of debugging and troubleshooting, invalidate/restart, sdk manager, gradle location, uninstalling and installing it again but it keeps saying gradle process sync failed,
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A build operation failed.
    Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Android Studio\gradle-8.9\caches\8.9\transforms\09058b5e4f2d733c396ac2094bcfc37d-8943f864-a152-438a-9207-7d121c190e1e) to immutable location (C:\Android Studio\gradle-8.9\caches\8.9\transforms\09058b5e4f2d733c396ac2094bcfc37d)


This question is similar to: React Native Error : java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
